# How to generate a MicroPython QSTR from a C macro?

Tags: c, micropython, precompiler

I'm using MicroPython and I would like to generate a QSTR that contains the contents of a macro. For example, I have the following macro:

```
#define MY_MACRO "hello"
```

How can I generate a QSTR that has the value "hello" and is called MP_QSTR_MY_MACRO?

When I use MP_QSTR_MY_MACRO, that QSTR contains "MY_MACRO" instead of "hello".

Comment: You may also want to ask over on the [micropython discussions](https://github.com/orgs/micropython/discussions).